# How can I get Visual Studio to always reload changed solutions, projects and files?

Tags: visual-studio, file, project, solution, reloading

I'm using multiple machines to profile and run one solution, with data synchronization done via DropBox (brilliant, btw!). Unfortunately, changes in one machine cause all other machines' VS instances to ask me whether I want to reload which is... annoying, because the answer is always *Yes*.

So my question is: can I get VS to assume that the answer is *always* Yes?

Answer (score 22):

Go to

> Options -> Environment -> Documents

Then check the boxes:

- "Detect when file is changed outside the environment"
- "Auto-load changes, if saved"

Tip: You're missing a trick not using proper source control.

Comment: Does this also apply to solutions and projects??

Comment: I don't know. I don't use it, but spotted it the other day trying to find something else.

Comment: I'm using proper source control as well, but I need something that can be updated *instantly*. Unless I am indeed missing something.

Comment: This does _not_ apply to projects/solutions.

Comment: Anybody has an idea on how to apply this to projects/solutions ?