# Is it possible to get Visual Studio to always reload changed solution and all projects without clicking "Reload All" button?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm working with **Visual Studio 2013**, and looking for answer in relation to VS2013 and/or VS2015.

There's this question here - but there's no answer to my question which is specifically to reload **solution** - 
[How can I get Visual Studio to always reload changed solutions, projects and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408906/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-to-always-reload-changed-solutions-projects-and-fil)

I know there was a lot more pain with this in VS2010, but I change branches often and it's still a pain to hit "Reload All" and wait until the whole solution is reloaded, I would rather prefer this happening automatically.

Just in case - this is my options for my editor
[image]